# What is a good redux-saga pattern to bootstrap an App that downloads data on start

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I have a web app that first loads data that takes 1-10 seconds.

I show full UI (a map) as soon as app starts and then kick off downloads in the background.

While data is downloading I would like to delay some effects such as showing route and search results).

Any actions debounced while data is loading (say user types search term) would be executed *after* data is loaded.

So:

```
App Starts 
      forks data download in background 
        shows UI
        lets user type -> debounce --> execute only after data has downloaded
         show more (route etc.) once download is complete
```

How do we do this in saga - which I believe is the most powerful of the frameworks to accomplish such tasks. I didn't see this as one of standard patterns but I would think it will be very common.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
function* fetchInitData(){}

function* setupLocale(){} 

function* submit(value){
   while(yield !select(state=>state.started)){
       yield delay(100);
   }
   yield call(fetch,...)
}
function* startSaga(){
   yield all[
      call(fetchInitData),
      call(setupLocale),
      delay(3000) // Wait at least 3 seconds
   ]
   yield put({
      type: "APP_STARTED",
   });    
}
```

Simply initialize your redux store app with `{started:false}` and reduce `APP_STARTED` action.